# acceptsFirstMouse click through on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, subclass, nscollectionview

I am trying to get click-though to work so that my application will respond to mouse clicks even when the window is inactive.  I have a collectionView with NSCollectionView items that respond to mouse events.  I have tried subclassing the view used by the collectViewItem, and have also subclassed the view used for the NSCollectionView.  It doesn't work.
code for the subclassed view looks like this:

```
import Cocoa

class SubclassedView: NSView {

  override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
      super.draw(dirtyRect)
  }

  // adding this override should allow click-through so buttons can be clicked even with an inactive window
  // it doesn't work
  override func acceptsFirstMouse(for event: NSEvent?) -> Bool {
      print("got first mouse")
      return true
  }

  override var acceptsFirstResponder :Bool {
      get {
          return true
      }
  }    
}
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just saw the same issue; subclassing `NSCollectionView` or the enclosing `NSClipView` or the `NSScrollView` didn’t work for me either.

What works is subclassing `NSView`, like you did:

```
class ClickThroughView: NSView {
    override func acceptsFirstMouse(for event: NSEvent?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

…and then setting the `NSCollectionViewItem`’s `view` to use this `ClickThroughView` class.

Be aware that e.g. an `NSImageView` sitting in front of our `ClickThroughView` will prevent the click event from reaching our subclass, so you’ll need to subclass `NSImageView` to accept the click-through as well.

Comment: I didn't know that NSImageView had an acceptsFirstMouse func that could be overridden.  Subclassing NSImageView works perfectly.

Comment: @DaveC Great! NSImageView inherits from NSView, so yes, sure. :) What I did by the way: Subclass the NSCollectionViewItem’s view as described above and then also subclass the NSImageView, returning nil in the hitTest(point:) method. This will also prevent the NSImageView from blocking the click.

Comment: Also had an image view blocking my button. Good call!

Comment: Here's a gist for quick plug & play → https://gist.github.com/tyirvine/93ee7b4d6f44ee333cdfc5f419f11389

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your window behaviour by adding below code:

```
window.collectionBehavior = .stationary;
window.level = .mainMenu + 1;
window.hidesOnDeactivate = false;
```